# How to measure Entity Ambiguity?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, metric, named-entity-recognition, research

When using/building a system for [Entity Linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking), is there a well-known measure for "ambiguity degree" of an entity?

Some approach to compare named entities regarding how difficult to disambiguate?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Linking is a type of supervised machine learning, thus many of the common performance metrics could be used. In particular, creating a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) would identify where one label was predicted but the ground-truth was different. Confusion matrices can be calculated with counts or normalized, a normalized data would be an estimate of "ambiguity degree" relative to the other labels in the current dataset.

Other classification measures such has F-score, precision, and recall could also be used. In particular, low precision for a label would suggest the model has trouble disambiguating entities from nearby text. "[Cheap and easy entity evaluation](http://acl2014.org/acl2014/P14-2/pdf/P14-2076.pdf)" goes into more technical details.

[Inter-rater reliability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability) could also be used, the raters could be different humans or different models. If the joint-probability of agreement between different raters is low then entities could be regarded as difficult to disambiguate.

The performance also depends on the relative value of an [exact match vs partial match](http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/05/09/Named_Entity_Evaluation/).

Answer (score 1):

[Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) is a common measure of uncertainty among a fixed set of choices, as are the ones provided by Brian Spiering.

Regarding your question -- "some approach to compare named entities regarding how difficult to disambiguate?" -- note that the difficulty to disambiguate an entity is completely context and domain dependent. To give a truly useful answer, you would need to provide more specifics about how your system will be used.